# pyspark get element from array Column of struct based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark df with the following schema:

```
 |-- col1 : string
 |-- col2 : string
 |-- customer: struct
 |    |-- smt: string
 |    |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |     |-- key: string
 |    |    |     |-- value: string
```

df:

```
#+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|col1   |col2   |customer                                                                   |
#+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|col1_XX|col2_XX|"attributes":[[{"key": "A", "value": "123"},{"key": "B", "value": "456"}]  |
#+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the json input for the array look like this:

```json
...
          "attributes": [
            {
              "key": "A",
              "value": "123"
            },
            {
              "key": "B",
              "value": "456"
            }
          ],
```

I would like to loop attributes array and get the element with `key="B"` and then select the corresponding `value`. I don't want to use explode because I would like to avoid join dataframes.
Is it possible to perform this kind of operation directly using spark 'Column' ?

Expected output will be:

```
#+-------+-------+-----+
#|col1   |col2   |B    |                                                               |
#+-------+-------+-----+
#|col1_XX|col2_XX|456  |
#+-------+-------+-----+
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `filter` function to filter the array of structs then get `value`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "B", 
    F.expr("filter(customer.attributes, x -> x.key = 'B')")[0]["value"]
)
```

Comment: it works like a charm. That's what I was looking for, thanks a lot!